# Counting points on the intersection of a box and a lattice

Tags: linear-algebra, lattices, geometry-of-numbers

Let $A:\mathbb{Z}^n\to \mathbb{Z}^n$ be non-singular. Consider a box $B=[0,N_1]\times [0,N_2] \times \dotsc \times [0,N_n]$. Let $p_1,\dotsc,p_n$ be primes (distinct, if you wish) and let $L = p_1\mathbb{Z} \times \dotsb \times p_n \mathbb{Z}$. Can one give a good bound on $A^{-1} L \cap B$? For instance, might $$|A^{-1} L \cap B| \ll \det(A) \prod_{1\leq i\leq n} \left(\frac{N_i}{p_{\pi(i)}} + 1\right)$$ hold for some permutation $\pi$ of $\{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$?

Assume all $p_i$ considerably larger than $n$ if needed. Also assume the matrix entries of $A$ to be bounded, if needed.

Note: I am not looking for an estimate with error term of size $\prod_{1\leq j\leq n-1} N_j$, say. That would be easy.

Comment: what are $\mathbb{Z}_i$ for different $i$?

Comment: Sorry, meant $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: If all $N_i$ are the same ($=N$) and the entries of $A$ are of absolute value $\leq c$, then it's easy to get a fairly good upper bound ($\leq \prod_i (c n N/p_i+1)$. The interesting case is that of $N_i$ not all of the same size.

Comment: (Of course one can always chop a box into cubes, but I am hoping for something better )

Comment: The Community Bot bumps this question every $120$ days.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not an answer, but too much for a comment:

Actually you can represent $L$ as a transformation of $\mathbb Z^n$ via $L=\Lambda \mathbb Z^n$, where $\Lambda=(\lambda_{ij})$ is the diagonal matrix such that $\lambda_{ii}=pi$. In the same way you can represent $N$ as $ME_n$ where $M=(m)_{ij}$ is the diagonal matrix with $m_{ii}=(N_i)$ and the unit cube $E_n=[0,1]^n \subset \mathbb R^n$ in the real vector space $\mathbb R^n$.
Then we get:
\begin{equation}
|A^{-1}L\cap N|=|\mathbb Z^n \cap (\Lambda^{-1}AM)E_n| 
\end{equation}
This suggests that $\det(\Lambda^{-1}AM)$ is useful, here. But this would be true only, if we would consider semi-open complete intervals in $\mathbb R^n$. So we must add another $1$ to each dimension on the $\mathbb Z^n$. This leads to the formula:
\begin{equation}
|\mathbb Z^n \cap (\Lambda^{-1}AM)E_n| \leq \det (\Lambda^{-1}AM +I)
\end{equation}

Maybe, some improvement can be achieved using the singular value decomposition 
\begin{equation}
\Lambda^{-1}AM = U \Sigma V^T.
\end{equation}
This would give you the intersection of a rotated orthogonal grid $U^T\mathbb Z^n$ with some rotated parallelepiped $\Sigma V^TE_n$: 
\begin{equation}
|\mathbb Z^n \cap (\Lambda^{-1}AM)E_n|=
|\mathbb Z^n \cap U\Sigma V^TE_n| =
|U^T\mathbb Z^n \cap \Sigma V^TE_n|
\end{equation}

Comment: so $det(A)∏_{i≤n}(N_i/p_{π(i)}+1)$ iff $1 ≪ \det A$ for some permutation $π$.